Experiencing Only Noise During Playback of PCM Audio Data Streamed via WebSocket in React Native and Swift
I'm developing a React Native application that receives PCM audio data over WebSocket, decodes it from a base64 string, and attempts to play it in real-time using an AVAudioEngine setup in Swift. Despite confirming that the audio data is correctly received by writing to file and playing it in Audacity, the playback in my app is only noise. I can't identify the cause.
JavaScript Code:
const handleAudioOutput = async (event) => {
    const arrayBuffer = event.data;
    const base64Data = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer).toString('base64');
    // await RNFS.appendFile(`${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/audioData.raw`, base64Data, 'base64');
    audioPlayer.current.playAudioData(base64Data);
};

useEffect(() => {
    audioOutputWs.current = new WebSocket(audioOutputUrl);
    audioOutputWs.current.onopen = () => console.log("Audio output ws open");
    audioOutputWs.current.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
    audioOutputWs.current.onmessage = handleAudioOutput;
  }, []);

On the swift side, we are buffering the received audio and playing from the buffer in a different thread.
Swift side Implementation:
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

@objc(AudioPlayer)
class AudioPlayer: NSObject {
  
  private var audioEngine: AVAudioEngine
  private var audioPlayerNode: AVAudioPlayerNode
  private var audioFormat: AVAudioFormat
  private var audioQueue: [Data]
  private let queueLock = NSLock()
  private var isProcessing = false
  
  override init() {
    audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    audioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    
    // Try using a common sample rate and format
    let sampleRate: Double = 24000.0
    let channelCount: AVAudioChannelCount = 1
    let commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat = .pcmFormatInt16
      
    guard let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: commonFormat, sampleRate: sampleRate, channels: channelCount, interleaved: false) else {
        fatalError("Failed to create AVAudioFormat")
    }

    
    audioFormat = format
    audioQueue = []
    
    super.init()
    
     audioEngine.attach(audioPlayerNode)
    // If I did format: audioFormat the constructor would crash So I found the below solution from some corner of the internet.
    audioEngine.connect(audioPlayerNode, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: AVAudioFormat.init(standardFormatWithSampleRate: 24000.0, channels: 1)!)

     do {
       try audioEngine.start()
     } catch {
       print("Failed to start AVAudioEngine: \(error)")
     }
    
     DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
       self.processAudioQueue()
     }
  }

  @objc(multiply:withB:withResolver:withRejecter:)
  func multiply(a: Float, b: Float, resolve: RCTPromiseResolveBlock, reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
    resolve(a * b)
  }

  @objc(add:withB:withResolver:withRejecter:)
  func add(a: Float, b: Float, resolve: RCTPromiseResolveBlock, reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
    resolve(a + b)
  }

  @objc(playAudioData:withResolver:withRejecter:)
  func playAudioData(base64String: String, resolve: RCTPromiseResolveBlock, reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String) else {
            reject("error", "Invalid base64 string", nil)
            return
        }

        queueLock.lock()
        audioQueue.append(data)
        queueLock.unlock()
        
        resolve(true) // Immediately resolve to not block the JS thread
  }

  private func processAudioQueue() {
      isProcessing = true
      while isProcessing {
          queueLock.lock()
          if !audioQueue.isEmpty {
              let data: Data = audioQueue.removeFirst()
              queueLock.unlock()
              
              let frameCount = AVAudioFrameCount(data.count / MemoryLayout<Int16>.size)
              guard let audioBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFormat, frameCapacity: frameCount) else {
                  continue
              }
              audioBuffer.frameLength = frameCount
              
              // Safe memory transfer using buffer pointers
              data.withUnsafeBytes { rawBufferPointer in
                  guard let bufferPointer = rawBufferPointer.bindMemory(to: Int16.self).baseAddress else {
                      return
                  }
                  guard let channelData = audioBuffer.int16ChannelData else {
                      return
                  }
                  
                  for frameIndex in 0..<Int(frameCount) {
                      channelData[0][frameIndex] = bufferPointer[frameIndex]
                  }
              }

              audioPlayerNode.scheduleBuffer(audioBuffer, at: nil, options: [], completionHandler: nil)
              
              if !audioPlayerNode.isPlaying {
                  audioPlayerNode.play()
              }
          } else {
              queueLock.unlock()
              usleep(10000) // Sleep for 10ms to avoid busy waiting
          }
      }
  }


  deinit {
    isProcessing = false
  }
}

What I've Tried:

Tried both Int16 and Float32
Tried both interleaved and non-interleaved settings.
Verified by writing it down to file and playing it. (Plays perfectly)
Just to verify more I tried to play the stream from same websocket over a python script using pyaudio and it played well. Here is the code for that:

async def _audio_player(self):
    """Asynchronously plays audio from the data received from ws."""
    self.stream_out = self.audio.open(
        format=8,
        channels=1,
        rate=24000,
        output=True,
    )
    while True:
        audio_bytes = await self.listen_to_audio_output()
        self.stream_out.write(audio_bytes)

